# How to figure out which Newtonsoft.JSON (Json.NET) nuget package to use with .net framework 4.5.2?

Tags: json.net, nuget

Okay, I give up.  Does anyone know the answer to this question?

**Bonus points, how to figure out which version for each target .net framework.**

(In general, I can't figure out using the nuget.org website which release targets a particular .net framework.)

Comment: create a console app and add json.net to it, if you want to target multiple platforms,try it on the portable class library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Newtonsoft.JSON: Currently the latest at the time of writing `10.0.2`.
In this case it is , you can see on package's [listing on NuGet.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) that there is dependencies section named ".NETFramework 4.5" so this indicates that there is a .NET Framework version targeted at version "4.5" which is the closest to the version of .NET Framework that you are using (4.5.2).

However, finding out what target frameworks a NuGet package really supports is difficult. Those dependencies nodes are only shown when the NuGet package expresses dependencies to other NuGet packages only for that framework. Or an empty list in that case (in some cases, like [JetBrains.Annotations](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JetBrains.Annotations/10.4.0), empty dependency groups are used to work around NuGet bugs or behaviours).

NuGet.org currently doesn't do a good job listing the supported frameworks that a package supports, since this is quite complicated.

First, you need to know which versions a package actively targets. The only source of truth here is to look at the packages contents. If you download and extract NewtonSoft.Json 10.0.2 (rename to "zip", extract), the available builds to choose from are in subfolders of a `lib` folder named after the "target platform moniker" that NuGet knows about:

[image]

For `net*` this is quite easy - if you have a .NET Framework app and reference a NuGet package with a `lib/net*/` subfolder, it will choose the version of the highest possible subfolder. But if there is only a `lib/net461` folder and your app targets .NET Framework 4.5.2, the package will be incompatible and won't install/restore.

The complicated part is that NuGet has a logic to fall back to other compatible frameworks. e.g. `netstandard1.0` versions can also be used in `net45` apps. This is how "Portable Class Libraries" (PCL) work. NuGet knows a lot of monikers like "portable-net40+sl5+win8+wpa81+wp8" and when you build a NuGet package for that "PCL profile", it knows from which applications it can be consumed (and `netstandard` aims to reduce all these names to a single versioned moniker).

The full "fallback and compatibility list" is only defined in code by the NuGet client, so depending on the version of your NuGet client (command line, .NET CLI, vision studio extension) it may know about different "names".

The list currently is in a [DefaultFrameworkMappings.cs file on GitHub](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/929b085c5c0e58280cc6950e9f05704bfbd8291c/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Frameworks/DefaultFrameworkMappings.cs) that is part of the NuGet client libraries.

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  I wanted to remove the warning "Some NuGet packages were installed using a target framework different from the current target framework and may need to be reinstalled." but when tried to follow another advice for upgrading, it really screwed up everything.

Changing the <HintPath> in the .csproj didn't remove the warning.

This successfully updated the Newtonsoft.JSON package (for .net 4.5.2):  **pmc>update-package newtonsoft.json**